# How do I draw M-PAM curves of Channel Capacity Vs SNR?

Tags: noise, digital-communications, graph, snr, signal-theory

I've seen the following figure in several different articles:

[image: C vs SNR]

(this one was taken from [here](http://www-classes.usc.edu/engr/ee-s/568/org/Forney-Ung.pdf))

I understand that channel capacity of the Gaussian signal is

```
C = 1/2 * log2(1 + SNR)
```

However, I don't understand how to get the other ones (**M-PAM** with **M=2,4,8...**). I've tried deducing the error probability and then using the channel capacity equation for a BSC channel to no good.

Does anyone have any pointers on this? I want to draw it with Matlab/Python/Whatever and see it with my own eyes :)

Comment: In situations where SNR is very high a 2-PAM system will level off at 2 bits per complex dimension and going upwards, every doubling of the PAM number equals 2^n where n is bits per dimension. Maybe I'm missing what your question really is about?

Comment: The equation for the Gaussion channel is C=1/2*log2(1+SNR). What is the equation for the M-PAM channels? How do I draw those curves in the graphic? That's the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No closed form expression exists for the capacities.
The best you can do is numerical approximation.

The capacity is the mutual information between Y and X, where Y=X+N, X is the constellation point (in your case a PAM), and N is Gaussian.

Then, the mutual information is I(Y;x) = H(Y) - H(Y|X).
The second term is easy (working it you yourself if you want).

For the second term you need to go numerical.
Here is the link to a nice matlab tool box. https://github.com/lacerbi/gmm1
What you need is gmm1ent.m.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with [user242153](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/242153/user242153), however, you can use H(Y|X)=H(x_i+N|x_i) with x_i as points in the constellation.

With that, H(x_i+N|x_i) is just the entropy of Gaussian Noise N(xi, sigma) and you can find the information for that here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy).

I have recently done it on python and I don't think there is a need for a numerical method.

Please correct me if I am wrong though, I am new to this.